# Problem arrow key navigation in textfield EXTJS

Tags: extjs

Arrow keys does not working properly in textfield when it's inseted in the grid's header.

Please find below an exemple to reproduce this behavior

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3e7u

Answer (score 0):

I didn't dive too deep, but it seems to be related to event propagation. As a workaround, you can add these lines to the `special` event listener function:

```
if (e.getKey() === e.LEFT || e.getKey() === e.RIGHT) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```